# Java Spring enums Jackson Serializer for data insertion/fetching

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, spring-mongo

I am trying to use enums in my project and need to save them in a mongoDB collection using lowercase and not UPPERCASE.

I have enums with a value String field and setter/getters annotated with Jackson's `@JsonCreator` and `@JsonValue`.

```
public enum State {
    GREEN   ("vert"),
    ORANGE  ("orange"),
    RED     ("rouge");

    private final String value;

    State(String val) {
        this.value = val;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static State fromValue(String value) {
        if (value != null) {
            for (State state : values()) {
                if (state.value.equals(value)) {
                    return state;
                }
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid state: " + value);
    }

    @JsonValue
    public final String toValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

I have a class using this enum like so:

```
@Document(collection = "my_collec")
public class MyClass {

    @Id
    private ObjectId _id;

    @Field("st")
    private State state;
.....
}
```

It works properly for the `@RequestBody` of my route, but when I try to fetch some data from mongodb where enums are saved as lowercased strings, it fails everytime with the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant package.enums.State.vert
at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:238) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
.....
```

Moreover, when I save some data using my repository, the saved enum is always UPPERCASE. I've placed breakpoints in my annotated functions and the code is never executed.

I then tried using `@JsonGetter` & `@JsonSetter`, `@JsonProperty` as well but it never worked...
I have also tried using custom Serializer/DeSerializer (`StdSerializer` and `JsonSerializer` with the same result.

Does anyone know what I am missing here ?

I am sorry to write one more post here on that subject I've almost browsed all of them without finding a working solution. 
Thanks in advance

PS: I found a hack to make it work but I really don't like it as we are parsing the enum in the getters/setters and storing it as a Stirng in the model.

Comment: jackson is not getting used to deserialize data while fetching from mongo db

Comment: try to define valueOf method in your enum as `public static State valueOf(String s) { return  fromString(s); }`

Comment: I tested in spring boot, with spring-data-mongodb, its working as expected.

Comment: Thanks @HemantPatel for clarification.
However I can't get your solution working, when I implement the function valueOf, my IDE tells me the function is already defined and I can't run the API anymore. I use java 1.8.

Comment: @Simon30 `valueOf` is a static function, i.e. you can't override it, you can only create a new definition inside `State`. If that definition is ever called depends on whether the framework (MongoDB driver in this case) picks up such a definition from your class, or just uses `Enum`s function. (I suspect the latter, and I wouldn't rely on it unless documented in the MongoDB driver definition: at least the Java MongoDB driver is failing on backwards compatibility in almost every version, and you don't want to add to that by using an obscure ability.)

Comment: java: method valueOf(java.lang.String) is already defined in enum